# Angular2: Support for withCredentials and useXDomain

Tags: angular, cross-domain, angular2-services, django-cors-headers

I am new to angular2.  I am trying to login to my Django server which is a production server from localhost where i am currently writing my front end code.  Also, I am port forwarding to my production server.
I keep getting the CORS issue.
Here is the error i get in my console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.smartkart.ca/api/user/login/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

I have written my HTTpService and have read almost all the blogs out there to figure out an solution but no luck.  I believe i need to use the withCredentials: true property.  I read some blogs and have modified my code to support withCredentials but no luck.

Here is my code snippet:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';


@Injectable()
export class HTTPService {
constructor(private _http: Http) {

}

baseUrl: String = "https://www.smartkart.ca/";
getStoreList() {        
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/current/store/')
        .map(res => res.json());
};

getCookie(name) {
    let value = "; " + document.cookie;
    let parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) 
    return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
};


login(){  
    // var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // var params = JSON.stringify({'email': 'karan@smartkart.ca', 'password': 'k0ttawa#1234'});
    // request.open('POST', this.baseUrl+ "api/user/login/", true);
    // request.onreadystatechange = function() {if (request.readyState==4) alert("It worked!");};
    // request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length.toString());
    // request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    // request.send(params);             
    var data = JSON.stringify({'email': 'test@smartkart.ca', 'password': 'blahblah'});     
    var params = data;  
    var headers = new Headers ();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('karan@smartkart.ca:k0ttawa#1234'));
    headers.append("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json");
    // headers.append("Content-length", params.length.toString());
    // headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // headers.append('Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'x-requested-with');
    // headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    // headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    // headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    // headers.append('Content-Type', 'pplication/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // headers.append('X-CSRFToken', this.getCookie('csrftoken'));

    return this._http.post(this.baseUrl+ "api/user/login/", params,
         {
             headers: headers
         }
    ).map(res => res.json())

};

}
```

here is what i see in my network tab in the browser

[image]

Now if i take away the authorization header i do get logged in and i get back the csrf token but i can never get any response from the server due to the CORS issue.  Here is a snapshot

[image]

I read some blogs where there were workarounds.  I tried that too but no success.

Here is my code for the workaround:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {BrowserXhr } from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class CORSBrowserXHr extends BrowserXhr {

build(): any {
    let xhr = super.build();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    return <any>(xhr);
}
}
```

And in bootstrap i add the following:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts" />
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";
import {BrowserXhr} from 'angular2/http';
import {CORSBrowserXHr} from "./CORSBrowserXHr.services";

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS,       provide(BrowserXhr, {useClass:CORSBrowserXHr}),
provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})]);
```

I understand angular2 is under beta but i believe that by now they must have comeup with a solution for CORS support.  If someone has any ideas please comment.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

In fact, there are two main cases in CORS:

- **Simple requests**. We are in this case if we use HTTP methods `GET`, `HEAD` and `POST`. In the case of `POST` method, only content types with following values are supported: `text/plain`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`. Even if you're in these case and if you use a custom header (a header that you define by your own in your request), you'll fall into the preflighted request.
- **Preflighted requests**. When you aren't in the case of simple requests, a first request (with HTTP method `OPTIONS`) is done to check what can be done in the context of cross-domain requests.

In your case, you're in the second case (preflighted request) since you use a custom header (defined by your own), the `Authorization` one.

But the corresponding OPTIONS request doesn't define a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in its response. This would allow the browser to determine if you're (localhost:3000 for example) able to execute the target request.

In fact, it's not a problem in your Angular2 application but in the server application you try to access. The latter should return the appropriate CORS headers like the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` one. Otherwise your browser will block the request...

These articles could interest you:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/
- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyBaseRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
  headers: Headers = new Headers({
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  });
  withCredentials: boolean = true;
}

bootstrap( AppComponent, [ provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: MyBaseRequestOptions}) ] );
```

Can you try with this , from : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4231

Comment: Do i need to inject it in bootstrap provider or I can directly use it in my httpService contructor?

Comment: You can add the Auth constructor code in your main constructor, where you are injecting the Http, that should be enough.

Comment: yes tried it, did not work. I added it directly to my httpservice contructor

Comment: can you create one Plunker for your problem so it would be easy to check.?

Comment: sure, will do that.  Will comment here once i have the plunker done

Comment: @KaranKhanna i had updated my answer can you try with that.?

Comment: This seemed to work, also I was doing one wrong thing.  I was directly calling the production server api while port forwarding. What i needed to do was to call my local server code which will then port forward to the production database.